# Displaying User Profile page externally

Tags: users

I have a custom page(Ex:usertest.php) in root folder and externally loaded drupal. If I print $user->uid it is displaying the user id. Upto now it is fine. But if I included the user-profile.tpl.php which exists in core "modules/user" folder, it is not working. From below code, it is not going to if loop. menu_get_object('user') is not wokring here. Any suggestions..

```
if($account = menu_get_object('user')) { 
    echo "User Profile Page"; 
}
```

## Code

```
<?php
global $user;
define('DRUPAL_ROOT',  '/var/www/sitename/doctors');
$drupal_url  = 'http://sitename/doctors'; // no trailing slashes
drupal_external_load($drupal_path, $drupal_url);
echo $uid = $user->uid;

/**************************************  Start - External Login related functions *********************************/
// load drupal stuff
function drupal_external_load($drupal_url) {
  global $base_url;

  // set drupal base_url (if not set set in settings.php)
  // because it's used in session name
  $base_url = $drupal_url;

  // save current path
  $current_path = getcwd();

  // move to drupal path, because it uses relative path for its includes
  chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);

  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
  // to use the drupal global user var (instead of session hack)
  // drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);

  // return the current path
  chdir($current_path);
}


// load a drupal user into the user obj
function drupal_external_userload($user_info = array()) {
  // Dynamically compose a SQL query:
  $query = array();
  $params = array();

  if (is_numeric($user_info)) {
    $user_info = array('uid' => $user_info);
  }
  elseif (!is_array($user_info)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  foreach ($user_info as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'uid' || $key == 'status') {
      $query[] = "$key = %d";
      $params[] = $value;
    }
    else if ($key == 'pass') {
      $query[] = "pass = '%s'";
      $params[] = md5($value);
    }
    else {
      $query[]= "LOWER($key) = LOWER('%s')";
      $params[] = $value;
    }
  }
  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {users} u WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $query), $params);

  if ($user = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $user = drupal_unpack($user);

    $user->roles = array();
    if ($user->uid) {
      $user->roles[DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID] = 'authenticated user';
    }
    else {
      $user->roles[DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID] = 'anonymous user';
    }
    $result = db_query('SELECT r.rid, r.name FROM {role} r INNER JOIN {users_roles} ur ON ur.rid = r.rid WHERE ur.uid = %d', $user->uid);
    while ($role = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $user->roles[$role->rid] = $role->name;
    }
    //user_module_invoke('load', $user_info, $user);
  }
  else {
    $user = FALSE;
  }

  return $user;
}


// don't send any headers before calling this
function drupal_external_login($username, $password) {
  global $user;

  if ( $user->uid > 0 ) {
    if ( $user->name != $username ) {
      drupal_external_logout();
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  require DRUPAL_ROOT. '/includes/password.inc' ;
  $account = user_load_by_name($username);
  if ( user_check_password($password, $account) ) {
    $user = $account;
    drupal_session_regenerate();
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}


function drupal_external_logout() {
  global $user;
  session_destroy();
  $user = drupal_anonymous_user();
}

/**************************************  Start - External Login related functions *********************************/
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to load Drupal?

Comment: I edited the question with code. Please check. In the 5th line of code, I need to include "User profile page" (i.e., user-profile.tpl.php)

Comment: you are calling `drupal_external_load($drupal_path, $drupal_url);` yet you haven't defined `$drupal_path` yet and then `drupal_external_load()` is defined with only one argument and then you try to use `$uid` that hasn't been defined and then have a bunch of other functions that don't seem to be ever called so..... it really is hard to figure out what you are asking here

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to load the user object, then I would suggest using `user_load()`.

To stay in your logic with `menu_get_object()`, I guess this fails, because you omit the third argument which sets the path, see the [doc](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7). If the path is not given it will default to the current request path which is probably not containing the users id in your case?! Try this:

```
menu_get_object('user', 1, 'user/' . $user->uid);
```

But this will result in the same as calling `user_load()`.

In order to use user.module funcitonality, which I guess is what you want, you could try to fake the request by manipulating $_GET, but even if that works, it's afaik considered bad practice.

Comment: Above you said is helpful for showing all field values in array. It's ok. In user-profile.tpl.php page, $pic = $user_profile['field_enterprise_blog_picture']; $pic  variable will show the user picture. This is not working here. Can we get it here?